# Nexus Oss error regarding connection

Tags: nexus, sonatype

[image]I am new nexus oss ( 3.2.0)  after installing and acessing nexus i could see some error in Log  look like there is connection issue  between nexus and outside world.

Logs are the following

```
2017-02-06 11:52:21,419+0000 INFO  [qtp1862376032-144] *UNKNOWN com.sonatype.nexus.analytics.internal.EventSubmitterImpl - Service URL: https://analytics.sonatype.com
2017-02-06 11:52:45,128+0000 WARN  [pool-39-thread-1] anonymous com.sonatype.nexus.plugins.outreach.internal.outreach.SonatypeOutreach - Could not download page bundle
org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to links.sonatype.com:80 [links.sonatype.com/207.223.241.68] failed: connect timed out
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:143) [httpcore:0.0.0]
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353) [httpcore:0.0.0]
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380) [httpcore:0.0.0]
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236) [httpcore:0.0.0]
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184) [httpcore:0.0.0]
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88) [httpcore:0.0.0]
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110) [httpcore:0.0.0]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184) [httpcore:0.0.0]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82) [httpcore:0.0.0]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:107) [httpcore:0.0.0]
        at com.sonatype.nexus.plugins.outreach.internal.outreach.OutreachConnector.get(OutreachConnector.java:136) [com.sonatype.nexus.plugins.nexus-outreach-plugin:3.2.0.01]
        at com.sonatype.nexus.plugins.outreach.internal.outreach.SonatypeOutreach.remote(SonatypeOutreach.java:206) [com.sonatype.nexus.plugins.nexus-outreach-plugin:3.2.0.01]
        at com.sonatype.nexus.plugins.outreach.internal.outreach.SonatypeOutreach.getPageBundle(SonatypeOutreach.java:159) [com.sonatype.nexus.plugins.nexus-outreach-plugin:3.2.0.01]
        at com.sonatype.nexus.plugins.outreach.Outreach$getPageBundle.call(Unknown Source) [3.2.0-01:na]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48) [groovy-all:2.4.7]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113) [groovy-all:2.4.7]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133) [groovy-all:2.4.7]
        at com.sonatype.nexus.plugins.outreach.internal.ui.OutreachComponent.readStatus(OutreachComponent.groovy:54) [com.sonatype.nexus.plugins.nexus-outreach-plugin:3.2.0.01]
        at com.sonatype.nexus.plugins.outreach.internal.ui.OutreachComponent$$EnhancerByGuice$$fcd4b7c.CGLIB$readStatus$6(<generated>) [3.2.0-01:na]
        at com.sonatype.nexus.plugins.outreach.internal.ui.OutreachComponent$$EnhancerByGuice$$fcd4b7c$$FastClassByGuice$$b3e1581a.invoke(<generated>) [3.2.0-01:na]
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.proxy.$MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) [com.google.inject:4.1.0]
        at com.google.inject.internal.InterceptorStackCallback$InterceptedMethodInvocation.proceed(InterceptorStackCallback.java:76) [com.google.inject:4.1.0]
        at com.palominolabs.metrics.guice.ExceptionMeteredInterceptor.invoke(ExceptionMeteredInterceptor.java:49) [com.palominolabs.metrics.guice:3.0.2]
        at com.google.inject.internal.InterceptorStackCallback$InterceptedMethodInvocation.proceed(InterceptorStackCallback.java:77) [com.google.inject:4.1.0]
        at com.palominolabs.metrics.guice.TimedInterceptor.invoke(TimedInterceptor.java:47) [com.palominolabs.metrics.guice:3.0.2]
        at com.google.inject.internal.InterceptorStackCallback$InterceptedMethodInvocation.proceed(InterceptorStackCallback.java:77) [com.google.inject:4.1.0]
        at com.google.inject.internal.InterceptorStackCallback.intercept(InterceptorStackCallback.java:55) [com.google.inject:4.1.0]
        at com.sonatype.nexus.plugins.outreach.internal.ui.OutreachComponent$$EnhancerByGuice$$fcd4b7c.readStatus(<generated>) [3.2.0-01:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [na:1.8.0_121]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) [na:1.8.0_121]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) [na:1.8.0_121]
        at com.softwarementors.extjs.djn.router.dispatcher.DispatcherBase.invokeJavaMethod(DispatcherBase.java:142) [org.sonatype.nexus.extdirect:3.2.0.01]
        at com.softwarementors.extjs.djn.router.dispatcher.DispatcherBase.invokeMethod(DispatcherBase.java:133) [org.sonatype.nexus.extdirect:3.2.0.01]
        at org.sonatype.nexus.extdirect.internal.ExtDirectServlet$3.invokeMethod(ExtDirectServlet.java:221) [org.sonatype.nexus.extdirect:3.2.0.01]
        at com.softwarementors.extjs.djn.router.dispatcher.DispatcherBase.dispatch(DispatcherBase.java:63) [org.sonatype.nexus.extdirect:3.2.0.01]
        at com.softwarementors.extjs.djn.router.processor.standard.StandardRequestProcessorBase.dispatchStandardMethod(StandardRequestProcessorBase.java:73) [org.sonatype.nexus.extdirect:3.2.0.01]
        at com.softwarementors.extjs.djn.router.processor.standard.json.JsonRequestProcessor.processIndividualRequest(JsonRequestProcessor.java:502) [org.sonatype.nexus.extdirect:3.2.0.01]
        at com.softwarementors.extjs.djn.router.processor.standard.json.DefaultJsonRequestProcessorThread.processRequest(DefaultJsonRequestProcessorThread.java:72) [org.sonatype.nexus.extdirect:3.2.0.01]
        at com.softwarementors.extjs.djn.servlet.ssm.SsmJsonRequestProcessorThread.processRequest(SsmJsonRequestProcessorThread.java:43) [org.sonatype.nexus.extdirect:3.2.0.01]
        at org.sonatype.nexus.extdirect.internal.ExtDirectJsonRequestProcessorThread.access$1(ExtDirectJsonRequestProcessorThread.java:1) [org.sonatype.nexus.extdirect:3.2.0.01]
        at org.sonatype.nexus.extdirect.internal.ExtDirectJsonRequestProcessorThread$1.call(ExtDirectJsonRequestProcessorThread.java:61) [org.sonatype.nexus.extdirect:3.2.0.01]
        at org.sonatype.nexus.extdirect.internal.ExtDirectJsonRequestProcessorThread$1.call(ExtDirectJsonRequestProcessorThread.java:1) [org.sonatype.nexus.extdirect:3.2.0.01]
        at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletScopes$4.call(ServletScopes.java:450) [com.google.inject:4.1.0]
        at org.sonatype.nexus.extdirect.internal.ExtDirectJsonRequestProcessorThread.processRequest(ExtDirectJsonRequestProcessorThread.java:75) [org.sonatype.nexus.extdirect:3.2.0.01]
```

Is there any way we can give Proxy seeting for nexus if yes how ? can someone guide me 
I could see  for some of component the status is showing as Online Remote connection pending .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is an option to add proxy for outbound connection under system ----> HTTP.
with that it worked fine.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The informational log message is because your computer is not connected to the outside world.  This is not a warning or error and will not affect your performance.

The screenshot strings you are seeing are because of confusing message in the NXRM3 system (and a deviance from NXRM2) as well as the fact that NXRM3 is not currently designed to reach out to the remote proxies before called.  This deviance is described here: https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-9878

These repositories are in fact ready to connect.  If they were failing (such as if you try and use them and your computer is not connected to the outside world), there would be a message such.  Once you connect with them (such as receiving a component from them) they will change to "Online - Remote Available".

In the next release of NXRM3 the message will change from "Online - Remote Connection Pending..." to "Online - Ready to Connect" to help alleviate this confusion.  Public ticket here: https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-11001

Comment: thanks  for the information , So  can we put any proxy setting in any of configuration file of nexus3  I couldn't find any setting files  where we can add the proxy  so that establish connection with internet .

Comment: @gibyalex Sorry I really don't understand your follow up question.  I imagine it should be a new SO or is appropriate for the Sonatype users list if anything however.